# Mocking dao calls in junit

Tags: mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock dao call in junit. I have a dao method `findById` which returns me an object of User. This can be done easily with similar to following example,

```
CustomerDAO customerDao = Mockito.mock(CustomerDAO.class);
Mockito.when(customerDao.findCustomerById(Mockito.anyLong()))
     .thenReturn(new Customer(1, "stackoverflow"));
```

But the User object which I am trying to populate has to many embedded entities in it. And to populate one user, I have to populate all of its embedded entities first(like UserAddress, UserActivity etc..). Which is resulting in lots of code to be written.

Please suggest do we have any simple method to populate the complete User entity along with its embedded entities object for mocking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mocking the *CustomerDAO* to test its functionality, you probably don't need to initialize the complete User class manually. So you can pass null values to the fields in your User object that aren't used in the test.

If you want to have/need the complete functionality of the User object with all its fields, you can mock those fields as well and pass them into the Customer object you created. You could also create a constructor with no arguments that initialize the fields to some default values and use those for testing.

Comment: Hi Vjeet, thank you for your suggestion. Yes, as said I can either mock embedded entities or initialize them with proper values so that I can run my test case. I have to right another 50 or more lines of code for populating this kind of object:)

Comment: You shouldn't have to write that much code for the function you want to test to function properly. Just use the default constructor of your customer object and mock the other objects inside your customer object.

If you really need all the information of your User object to be created properly, you should probably think about an integration test instead

Comment: Yes Vjeet. I will try this approach. Thank you:)